# Tag autocomplete in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, autocomplete

I have a collection of documents with `tags` arrays, containing 0+ strings.

I want to offer a search by tag UI field that autocompletes valid tags. This would be done by having a collection of all those tags, which is essentially an index of the tags field, and doing, i.e., `{tags:{$regex:/^ro/}}` as each character is typed in the field. As they type, valid tags such as "rome", "role", etc appear.

Once some tags are specified in the UI, the user performs an actual search that includes the tags among other things, doing a regular `find` expression. **I do not want text search for the tags field, so please don't suggest that.**

In other words, for the tag autocomplete, I *don't need* the references to the documents tagged, I only need a list of the tags that match the regex.

Do I need to maintain my own collection of tags, or can I somehow use a `tags` index for this?

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution for this:

```
db.test.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": {path:"$tags"}},
  { "$match": {tags:{$regex:/^ro/}} },
  { "$group": {"_id":null, "tags":{"$addToSet":"$tags"}}}
])
```

It does give me the results I need, though I'm not sure if there's a better form of the query. Performance seems no worse than similar queries that don't compact results the way I want.